# MATLAB - Contour plot with only 2 colours?

Tags: matlab, contour

I am plotting contour plots in matlab using vectors. I am using the contourf command for filled contour. The thing is that my data is discrete initially (only has values 0 & 1) but still matlab interpolates the color in the contour plot, which I don't want. I want only two colors for the plot - 0 defining black, 1 defining white. Also these colors should represent the actual data being plotted.

Comment: Could you add code example that you tired? And what result you expect?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify levels in `contourf`:

```
%# create contours with colors indicating 0 and 1
contourf(X,Y,Z,[0 1])

%# set the colormap to black/white
colormap([0 0 0;1 1 1])
```

Comment: Your answer is OK, I just don't understand advantage of contour plot over `imagesc` for two-level data. Cutted corners?

Comment: @anandr: I guess the smoothing is what the OP is looking for, but I do agree that `imagesc`, followed by the same call to `colormap` as above should do the trick nicely as well.